# Asking my bash to skip ssl checking

Tags: apache, bash, ubuntu, ssl

I have a machine, in which apache is running. I configured apache to get the ssl certificate from location `/ssl`. I can hit my site `www.batman.com` and there is no ssl error in my browser.

But when I try :

```
wget localhost
```

I get an huge error:

```
ERROR: no certificate subject alternative name matches
    requested host name `localhost'.
To connect to localhost insecurely, use `--no-check-certificate'.
```

I know my ssl certificate doesn't match the name `localhost`. But my problem is I'm running a script downloaded from [here](http://exchange.nagios.org/directory/Plugins/Web-Servers/Apache/check_apache2-2Esh/details).

when I run:

```
./check_apache2.sh -H localhost -P 8443
```

I get an error:

```
(standard_in) 2: syntax error
OK - Apache serves  Requests per second with an average CPU utilization of 0.5%. Busy workers: , idle:  | 'cpu_load'=0.5 'req_psec'= 'bytes_psec'= 'bytes_preq'= 'workers_busy'= 'workers_idle'=
```

I guess the error is due to ssl certificate reason.

Are there any way to say my script that don't do ssl certificate check same as what `wget` provides with `no-check-certificate`?

I'm new to bash. Kindly help

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That looks like a syntax error; are you sure that it's due to the SSL cert?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
./check_apache2.sh -H localhost -P 8443 -S
```

According to the docs, the `-S` does https and invokes wget with the `--no-check-certificate` flag.

Comment: @batman then your assumption: "*I guess the error is due to ssl certificate reason*" is incorrect.

Comment: Yes. The plugin uses the apache server-status page to get info. I haven't enabled it. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @batman It looks like the error is thrown by `bc -l`, because if the server-status page is missing, the script tries to subtract to blanks instead of 2 numbers and `bc` pukes.